# how to pass the current tag instance to the events in angular2

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular2-directives

I have a left sidebar menu which is populated by `<li>` and `<ul>` tag elements. I have handled the menu click event to expand/collapse the sub-menu items.

The problem I am facing here is I am not able to pass/identify the current instance of the tag element to do the expand/collapse i.e. If i expand a particular menu item all the other menus items are also getting affected. How do i handle this issue by identifying the current instance to do the required changes.

Please refer the snapshot about the issue
[image]

my HTML looks like below

```html
<li [class.active]="menuLinkActive" (click)="MenuLinkToggle($event)">
    <a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="nav child_menu" [style.display]="subMenuDisplay">
        <li>
            <a href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index2.html">Dashboard2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="index3.html">Dashboard3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
 <li [class.active]="menuLinkActive" (click)="MenuLinkToggle($event)">
    <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav child_menu" [style.display]="subMenuDisplay">
        <li>
            <a href="form.html">General Form</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="form_advanced.html">Advanced Components</a>
        </li>
         </ul>
</li>
```

my component where i have handled the events

```js
export class Layout {
    menuLinkActive: any;
    subMenuDisplay: any;
    isSubMenuExpanded: any;
    isMenuVisible: any;

    MenuLinkToggle(event) {
        if (this.isSubMenuExpanded) {
            console.log("if (this.isMenuExpanded) {");
            this.menuLinkActive = "";
            this.subMenuDisplay = "none";
            this.isSubMenuExpanded = false;
        }
        else {
            console.log("else (this.isMenuExpanded) {");
            this.menuLinkActive = "active";
            this.subMenuDisplay = "block";
            this.isSubMenuExpanded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li [class.active]="menuLinkActive" #li1 (click)="MenuLinkToggle($event, li1)">
```

```
MenuLinkToggle(event, element) {
```

or

```
    MenuLinkToggle(event) {
      event.target...
```